# CartThrob 2.5 with Profile:Edit 1.1.8 Member Field Mapping Issue

Tags: cartthrob, profile-edit

I am using CartThrob 2.5 with Profile:Edit 1.1.8 and it will not let me map the the Profile:Edit member fields. All the dropdown menus are blank. Is this a bug?

Has anyone found a solution for this issue?  I ma using EE 2.7.3, CT 2.5 and PE 1.1.8 and still can't map PE fields in CT.  I have many fields setup in the channel but they do not show up on mapping page.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you definitely told CT which channel is the member profile channel?

Comment: Actually, ignore that, it should pick it up automatically.

Comment: I have the channel all setup with about 30 fields and it is setup in PE.  No idea why CT will not see it.

Comment: is this a Multi-site manager site? Or a single site?

Comment: Hey Chris. I have a session setup with you tomorrow. I will show you what is happening. I get same issue on two servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the fix:

1. Open P:E's config.php file. Change the file number from 1.1.8 to 1.1.81.
2. Go to EE > addons > modules > run module updates

That should fix the whole thing. The root of the problem is that EE changed their extension hooks from safecracker to channel form from 2.5 to 2.7. P:E's set to change the hook, but it looks like it had been updated before EE had. Basically the hook in the database was wrong. CT was looking to see if P:E was installed based on the existence of that hook. There's a few places we'll fix in CT and P:E to rectify this for the next release. In the meantime, you can run the fix above if this happens to you.

Comment: I have a support call setup for 2 PM tomorrow Chris.  We can go over the issue then in detail.  I will send you a meeting invite so we can screenshare to your work email address.